# Why is this pointer treated as an rvalue in this scenario?

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue

The following will not work:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
int **ptr = &(arr.data());
```

because I would be trying to take the addr of an rvalue. I've gotten around it with:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
int *ptr = arr.data();
int **ptr2 = &ptr;
```

which seems to work just fine.

I understand you cannot take the address of an rvalue, but why is it treated so here? Is it because a temporary will be created from `arr.data()` and then assigned to `ptr` and I'd be trying to take the address of that temporary?

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place?? This `int *ptr = arr.data();
int **ptr2 = &ptr;` seems bizzare to me.

Comment: I'm very puzzled.  "Why is this pointer treated as an rvalue?" "Because it is an rvalue."  "Why does this work around work?" "because in it, the pointer isn't an rvalue."  Are you really asking "what are rvalues, and what do they have to do with pointers?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because a temporary will be created from `arr.data()` and then assigned to `ptr` and I'd be trying to take the address of that temporary?

Yes.  Anything that returns by value returns an rvalue.  `std::array::data` return `T*`, not `T*&`, so it's return value is an rvalue.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this pointer treated as an rvalue in this scenario?
>
> ```
> &(arr.data())
> ```

Because `std::array::data` returns a value. The result of the call is a prvalue. Prvalues are ("pure") rvalues.